# Confused by SCOPE_IDENTITY() and GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a bit confused by the documentation & behavior of SCOPE_IDENTITY() in SQL Server.

This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 says this about SCOPE_IDENTITY():

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or **batch**. Therefore, if two statements are in the same
>   stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

And it contains this example

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
INSERT INTO Person.ContactType ([Name]) VALUES ('Assistant to the Manager');  
GO  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];  
GO  
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [@@IDENTITY];  
GO
```

Which returns

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY  
21  
@@IDENTITY  
21
```

From the docs I would have thought that the result of SCOPE_IDENTITY() would be NULL because SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY]; is executed in a different **batch** (because it comes after GO) than the INSERT command... What am I missing here?

Comment: What program did you use to send those commands to the database server?

Comment: The example is from the documentation, but we see the same behavior in SQL Server Management Studio (for a different table).

Answer (score 5):

I'd agree, I think the documentation is slightly misleading. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` *does* retain its value across multiple batches directly executed on the same connection.

But note that if you create an *inner* batch, by executing `EXEC` with a string, that inner batch's `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is independent from *your* outer batch's `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

---

This script produces the value `2`, not `5`:

```
create table T1 (ID int IDENTITY(2,1000) not null,Val char(1))
create table T2 (ID int IDENTITY(5,1000) not null, Val char(1))
go
insert into T1(Val) values ('a')
exec('insert into T2(Val) values (''b'')')
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `scope_indentity`.  SQL Server has a much, much better way of returning values from the insert, the `OUTPUT` clause.

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id INT);

INSERT INTO Person.ContactType ([Name])
    OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @ids  -- I'm not sure what the identity is named
    VALUES ('Assistant to the Manager');
```

This has multiple advantages:

- You can return more columns than just the `id`.
- You can return the ids from inserts that have more than one row.
- You don't have to worry about scoping at all.